# Python shopping list text application, saving issues

Tags: python, list, save

I'm trying to learn python and as a project I started to make a shopping list text script. The script is supposed to ask if you want to either add/delete an item to your list. It also has the function to print your list. You can save the list as a .txt document and continue on in when you want.

My first problem was that when I saved the list items and brought them back all the different list items had become one list item. So I could add, but I could not remove singular items from the list.

I have now tried to split the lists from the .txt document. I think that this splits the list, but now its adding extra symbols every time i start the script save it, and then start it again. Is there some small adjustments I can make or is my idea miles off?

```
#I think the main problem is in the program_start_list_update_from_file defenition

# Shopping list simulator
shoppingList = []

def program_start_list_update_from_file():
    global shoppingList
    outputname = "shoppinglistfile.txt"
    myfile = open(outputname, 'r')
    lines = str(myfile.read().split(', '))
    shoppingList = [lines]
    myfile.close()

def shopping_list_sim():
    print("Would you like to add (a) delete (d) or list (l) items in your shopping list?")
    print('Press (e) for exit and (s) for list saving')
    playerInput = input()
    outputname = "shoppinglistfile.txt"


    try:
        if playerInput == "a":
            print("What item would you like to add?")
            shoppingList.append(input())
            print("Item added")
            shopping_list_sim()


        elif playerInput == "d":
            print("What item would you like to remove?")
            print(shoppingList)
            shoppingList.remove(input())
            print("Item removed")
            shopping_list_sim()

        elif playerInput == "l":
            myfile = open(outputname, 'r')
            yourResult = ', '.join(myfile)
            print(yourResult)
            shopping_list_sim()


        elif playerInput == "e":
            print("Exiting program")
            sys.exit()

        elif playerInput == "s":
            myfile = open(outputname, 'w')
            myfile.write(', '.join(shoppingList))
            myfile.close()
            shopping_list_sim()
        else:
            print("Please use the valid key")
            shopping_list_sim()
    except ValueError:
        print("Please put in a valid list item")
        shopping_list_sim()

program_start_list_update_from_file()
shopping_list_sim()
```

Comment: Can you provide some example output and a sample of the saved list?

Comment: Yes, added key, banana and carrot. After first save .txt file is [''], key, banana, carrot. Second time opening program and adding mouse and after this saving. Result: ["['']", 'key', 'banana', 'carrot'], mouse. Third time adding the word instance and saving. Result: ['["[\'\']"', "'key'", "'banana'", "'carrot']", 'mouse'], instance. @TemporalWolf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The source of the issue is

```
lines = str(myfile.read().split(', '))
shoppingList = [lines]
```

You're splitting the file into a list, making a string out of that list, then adding that single string into a list.

```
shoppingList = myfile.read().split(', ')
```

is sufficient to do what you want: `split` creates a list for you.

---

You should consider switching from recursive calls to a loop:
Each recursive call adds overhead as it builds a new [stack frame](https://www.cs.ucsb.edu/~pconrad/cs8/topics.beta/theStack/02/), which in this case is completely unnecessary.

They way you currently have it, every new prompt has a new stack frame:

```
shopping_list_sim()
    shopping_list_sim()
        shopping_list_sim()
            shopping_list_sim()
                ...
```

If you do it in a loop, you don't recursively build the stack.

Comment: This solved it! Now the only problem is the way it outputs the text, if I list the items it starts with , keyless, banana. So it puts an extra symbol also when I want to delete an item the list looks like ['', 'keyless', 'banana']. Do you know how to fix that?

Comment: With the code you supplied, I don't see that via [repl.it](https://repl.it/FCe6/0)

Comment: I think it has something to do with repl not saving it to a .txt file. Also the reason why its printing ['', 'keyless', 'banana'] when deleting items as a "preview" list is because I am printing the list. Solved this by doing `print(', '.join(shoppingList))`. Problem is still that its adding " ," to the start of all lists.

Comment: Your code doesn't exhibit that behavior even if I run it via the commandline: `python3 shop.py`. I added error handling, but didn't change the list logic other than listed above.

Comment: The extra " ," is probably coming from `elif playerInput == "s":
            myfile = open(outputname, 'w')
            myfile.write(' ,'.join(shoppingList))
            myfile.close()
            shopping_list_sim() `

Comment: @FredomTrucer I cannot replicate that issue with the supplied code. Neither locally nor through repl.it. There are other concerns with your code, namely a loop would much more elegantly solve the issue of repeatedly prompting for user input.

Comment: Okay, no problems it is a minor detail. The main function of the script works now so that's the most important thing. I know this goes a bit off-topic but why would a loop be better in a situation like this? Is it more efficient? Also I consider this issue to be solved, thank you for your help!

Comment: @FredomTrucer I appended an answer to that question onto my original answer.